# Grabbing a value from Config using Java

Tags: java, minecraft

I am working on a mod for Minecraft but there is 1 last piece of code giving me trouble. I am not very knowledgeable about this code so i cant work through the error as normal and Eclipse dose not give any option to fix it.
I am trying to grab a Value from the Config

```
B:CreativeBiomeConfig = false
```

When this is set to true is should Register the Biome

```
GameRegistry.addBiome(CreativeBiome);
```

The current code I am using is a boolean but gives the following error

> The operation == is undefined for the argument type(s) int, boolean

```
if (this.CreativeBiomeConfig == true){
 GameRegistry.addBiome(CreativeBiome);
}
```

Pastbin for Classes

http://pastebin.com/hR5zpbE3

http://pastebin.com/4iVjxvXS

http://pastebin.com/iEJ4M32f

Comment: It looks like your definition of CreativeBiomeConfig results in an integer .. where do you define this?

Comment: I edited the question to include the classes used in in the config

Comment: Just as an additional question is it possible to change 

B:CreativeBiomeConfig to B:SpawnCreativeBiome without to much editing ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to read a boolean value from your configuration file, you should use `getBoolean` method (`true` in `getBoolean(true)` indicates the default value):

```
CreativeBiomeConfig = config.get(Configuration.CATEGORY_GENERAL, "CreativeBiomeConfig", true).getBoolean(true);
```

You should also make sure that the `CreativeBiomeConfig` field in your class is declared as boolean:

```
public static boolean CreativeBiomeConfig;
```

Of course, you can change the name of the setting (second argument of `config.get`) if you want to, you don't have to rename variables in your code:

```
CreativeBiomeConfig = config.get(Configuration.CATEGORY_GENERAL, "SpawnCreativeBiome", true).getBoolean(true);
```